# apt update shows neon kde repo link error

Tags: kde

Recently I use apt update on my machine and it gives me the following error:

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.neon.kde.org/user xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Here is my `lsb_release -a` output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I went to that link no file was found there. What should I do now?

Comment: KDE Neon has no support for xenial/16.04, as flavors only come with 3 years of support, 16.04 reaching EOL for official *flavors* of 16.04 in 2019-April (with the lon exception of *Kylin* which Canonical offered support for 5 years), which I guess applies with KDE & Neon too.  When resources reach EOL, a number of official & *flavor* sites remove the repositories (not all do this).

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Kubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks, or use Ubuntu's default Unity desktop (*which still is supported*).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I should update my system then. There is no specific point for me to linger around anyway.